# Apache - client denied by server configuration

Tags: apache

Hi I have installed apache but i am getting following error in my error log when accessing localhost

Apache - client denied by server configuration

Please help me to help this
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have some `Deny` specifications in your httpd.conf or .htaccess file blocking your request.  It's hard to say more without knowing exactly what's in those conf files.

Comment: I got it fixed. 
In conf i was not giving proper. 

Thanks for reply

Comment: @RoyalPinto - what do you mean you were "not giving proper" - can you explain as I am facing the same issue.